# Best way to validate the value of an input field immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The best way to validate and display the user input on the fly?

Comment: recommend changing title to "field" to aid SEO.

Comment: What user input? What validation requirements? What have you attempted, where's your code (HTML, JavaScript, jQuery...)? How do you define 'best'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by intercepting one of the key events for that given text box, and then doing validation on each keypress. If you want to do this for the copy-paste as well, you can add a duplicate on the on paster event as well.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#txtTime").keydown(function() {

        if(!pattern.test($("#txtTime").val()))
        {
            $("#txtTime").css("invalid");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#txtTime").css("valid");
        }
    });

    $("#txtTime").on('paste', function() {

        if(!pattern.test($("#txtTime").val()))
        {
            $("#txtTime").css("invalid");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#txtTime").css("valid");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Good) But it's possible to change value with dom inspector, like firebug and etc.

Comment: You should also be doing server side validation alongside it either way, and you would always be able to bypass it client side since they have control over the page.

Comment: @devone simply change it to ^[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$

Answer (score 0):

If server-side validation is required, then wrap input field into a form element. Set action attribute of form with url of validation script.
And then:

```
$('#your-form-id').on('submit', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(e.target).attr('action'),
        type: $(e.target).attr('method'),
        data: $(e.target).serialize(),
        success: function (answer) {
            if (answer.valid) {
                // do "next step"
            }
            else {
                // do "invalid field step"
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```